# count and fetch rows in php

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table in my mysql database named  (names)  now everyone can save their real names

now i want to query this table and find out how many times these names used

forexample the output should be  :

> Jakob (20)   Jenny (17)

now this is my own code :

```
    list($usernames) =mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SELECT name FROM table_user GROUP BY name ORDER BY COUNT(name) DESC LIMIT 50 '));
    list($c) =mysql_num_rows(mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(name) FROM table_user GROUP BY name '));

    print $usernames.'('.$c.')'
```

is this a correct approach ?!

Comment: Why are u using DESC LIMIT 50?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use one select query for this:

```
$sel_query=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(name) AS nums, name FROM table_user GROUP BY name");
```

For outputting, you can use something like this:

```
while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($sel_query))
{
   echo $fetch['name']."( ".$fetch['nums']." ) ";
}
```