# Count function not counting all rows in db table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to count the number of rows in a table, using the count function. I currently have 5 rows in the table in question. However the count function is only counting 1 row. Why is this? Any suggestions.

```
 $count_pcode = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT COUNT(*)FROM Delivery_Pcode");
 $count_row =mysqli_num_rows($count_pcode);
 printf("%d results.\n",$count_row);
 mysqli_free_result($count_pcode );
 mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Comment: Only one row is returned when you do a count; the value returned in that row contain the count value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [count and fetch rows in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721023/count-and-fetch-rows-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$count_pcode = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM Delivery_Pcode");
$count_row = mysqli_num_rows($count_pcode);
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Let's return the entire table from MySQL to PHP, potentially consuming considerable CPU, RAM and network bandwidth—solely in order to obtain a simple integer.  Fantastic work!  Well done.

Comment: @eggyal calm down, lad. We're both just giving him the answer he wanted.

Comment: @Blue no problem! Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Just change the first line to:

```
$count_pcode = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM Delivery_Pcode");
```

The next line of code will then tell you how many rows your query return

```
$count_row =mysqli_num_rows($count_pcode);
```

Comment: Damn, you bet me by 20s xD

Comment: Brilliant.  Let's return the entire table from MySQL to PHP, potentially consuming considerable CPU, RAM and network bandwidth—solely in order to obtain a simple integer.  Fantastic work!  Well done.

Comment: If you leave the original query as is, you could change the next line to `$count_row = $count_pcode->fetch_row()[0];` and get the result you want without returning the entire recordset worth of data.

Answer (score 2):

This code should count the number of rows, and do so efficiently.

```
$result = mysql_query($dbc, "SELECT COUNT(*)FROM Delivery_Pcode");

// Verify it worked
if (!$result) echo mysql_error();

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

// Should show you an integer result.
print_r($row);

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($dbc);
```